# Keyerror by find method in XML etree child

Tags: python-3.x

i create a simple xml structure:

```
import xml.etree.cElementTree as ET
root = ET.Element("root")
doc = ET.SubElement(root, "doc", name="doc1")

ET.SubElement(doc, "rank").text = "Employee"
ET.SubElement(doc, "skill").text = "nothing"
```

Now i want to return the values but i get this error: "KeyError: 'Employee'"

```
for doc in root.findall('doc'):
    rank = doc.find('rank').text
    skill = doc.find('skill').text
    name = doc.get('name')
    Logging(name, rank, skill)
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is the parameters in the Logging method.

I switch Logging to print and everthing is working.